# "...based on the sub-graphs themselves" grammaticality

Tags: relative-pronouns, redundancy

I tried to join several sentences together, and I ended up with this:

> To this end, we introduce a method to recognize semantic phenomena of
>   vertices points through sub-graphs available in the Main graph and then
>   geometrically fix such vertices at high precision, based on the
>   sub-graphs **themselves**.

I'm worried that the word *themselves* at the end is incorrect. Is this sentence grammatical?

Comment: As it stands, this question is proofreading (which is off topic here). If you have a specific concern about part of the sentence which you think is incorrect, please edit to point it out and I will be happy to reopen this question :) (At first glance though, you sentence is easily understandable at least.)

Comment: @WendiKidd: i guess, the term "theselves" make my sentence grammatically out. how would it be rectified.

Comment: niro, edited to reflect and reopened :)

Answer (score 1):

There are some mistakes in that sentence. But using "themselves" is not one of them as far as I can see. For example, "Vertices" "point through", not "points through", a "the" is needed before sub-graphs etc. To make the sentence clearer, introduce some more words. Like if you say it in this way:

> To this end, we introduce a method to recognize semantic phenomena of vertices **which** point through **the** sub-graphs available in the Main graph and then geometrically fix such vertices at high precision, based on those **very same** sub-graphs themselves.

This **very same** part helps the readers understand that the sub-graphs are the same sub-graphs which are available in the main graph (*if that is true at all; I interpreted this way*).

However despite this improvement, the sentence still lacks readability. Based on your questions, you asked lately, it seems that you are inclined to join small sentences on Mathematics to make longer one. I don't know why you are interested in longer sentences, but let me tell you when you give lecture on some subject, the lecture should be easy to interpret, so that the audience, for whom the lecture is intended to, can comfortably understand your articulation (*especially when the subject is mathematics which most of the average people consider "a dry subject"*). So I would rather suggest you, using simple and small sentences to allow listeners to understand clearly. You know how you could have said these long sentence dividing into small sentences.

Answer (score 0):

Your use of "themselves" is quite fine, which states explicitly that the sub-graphs in an early clause are the sub-graphs you refer to in the final clause. You might wish to split the sentance into two to make it a bit "easier to chew", such as:

> To this end, we introduce a method to recognize semantic phenomena of
>   vertices points through sub-graphs available in the Main graph; one
>   can then geometrically fix such vertices at high precision, based on
>   the sub-graphs themselves.

However this is not strictly necessary, and if you feel it reduces clarity or precision then you may safely stick with your original form.